# unable to access to an url using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I imported that library :

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

I have this code :

```
const test =  () => {
    return <Redirect to="https://www.google.fr/" />
    }
  };
```

Using that button :

```
<Button variant="outline-success" onClick={() => test()}>Search</Button>
```

When I click on that button there is no effects ...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router is meant for internal navigation within your application and can only redirect to internal routes.

In order to redirect to an external url, you can do the following:

```
const test =  () => {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.fr/";
  }
};
```

If you want to have a clickable button that links to your external url, then using the `a` tag with the external url as the `href` property is a better solution, and you can then customize the styling of your `a` link to make it look like a button.

Comment: Not the most SEO-friendly way to do it. You are supposed to use a `<a>` instead of `<button>` for that case.

Comment: @MatthewKwong Agreed, I updated my answer to mention that using an html link is better for this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not how `Redirect` supposed to work. You are supposed to redirect to an internal link, not external.

Second, You are trying to return a component in a `onClick` event handler. Clearly, it will do nothing.

Just use normal `<a>` for external links. Or make the `Button` component an `a` and pass `href="https://www.google.fr/"` to it.

e.g. this is how MUI do it:

```
<Button component="a" href="https://google.com">To Google</Button>
```